# Can I enforce cascade delete in a delete from statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete, cascade

I am using constraints in a database meaning that records of a certain table cannot be removed lightly. That is normally the desired case.

However, is there a way to write a DELETE FROM query so that for every constraint that would normally block the removal of record/s, *cascade delete* will be used?

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? IE Start and end results of what you're looking for, table structure etc.

Comment: The question is about a database with any table structure.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, the way to do this is a foreign key whith `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But you don't want this, so I see 2 options (there may be more as I'm not a SQL Server expert):

- Make this in the hard way: write [multi-table DELETE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql) statements. As you can see in the documentation, it is very similar to a `JOIN`.
- If you want to do this easy (for example to hide information about database structure to developers), you'll need a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger. This trigger can delete rows from other tables. I understand that you want this to happen only in certain cases; this is doable by setting (before your query) and checking (in the trigger) [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql). Rows will only be deleted if the variable is set. It should be unset at the end of the trigger itself, so developers won't need to take care of this (they could forget). Since the trigger will delete relevant rows before the query is executed, the constraint will not make it fail.
- A very similar approach, but maybe cleaner, would be writing a stored procedure.

Comment: What I seek is a syntax of DELETE FROM where I do not have to know which other tables that are affected by the operation of deleting a single record of a certain table. Like if every constraint in the database was "cascade delete" already.

Comment: Understandable, but you'll have to choose one of existing possibilities. Though, as I stated, I may have missed some of them.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no such syntax of DELETE FROM?

Comment: Definitely not, please read the answer so I don't have to repeat :) But if you ask for a syntax "where I do not have to know which other tables that are affected by the operation", then I really believe that the answer is no. Let's see if some SQL Server expert shows that I'm wrong.

Comment: @AndersLindén  Seek and get are not the same.  You could probably read system tables to build up the delete statements.